# Why is Windows Explorer not updating when I do things?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

Right now, if I rename a file in windows explorer, or right click->create new folder (or new file), or do a bunch of other things, I don't see the result of the action (i.e., the file's name stays the same, or the new folder/file doesn't appear) until I click away to another folder, and then back to the one I did the action in.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

I am using Windows 8.

Comment: You can do a view-->refresh.  I'm not sure you are going to be able to change this behavior unless you lobby M$ pretty heavily.

Comment: @mdpc - I can change the name of a file on my system and the list of files are updated right away.  This sounds case of needing to set the folder view settings to default.  **This is a configuration problem not a software problem.**

Comment: @mdpc, seriously? This is new behavior this week for some reason. But that would be a pretty massive flaw for an OS to have. You can't reasonably use a system that does crap like this.

Comment: @Ramhound, Thank you, do you know what I can do? I haven't changed anything that I know of, but maybe some update did.

Comment: Have you tried to restore the folder view default settings?

Comment: @Ramhound, Yes, that didn't work. Thank you, but not having actions update is clearly not just a setting...

Comment: @YungHummmma - Its is;  I have enabled it by accident; that's how I know.